# Organize data from two lists or arrays into dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that that are related. `name1` is the name for the value `1424`. My goal is to be able to organize and access the data based upon their name.

```
list1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name2', 'name1', 'name1']
list2 = [1424, 5243, 1200, 3498, 9087, 4390]
```

I want to create a dictionary that results in something like this:

```
{ 'name1': [1424,9087, 4390], 
  'name2': [5243,3498], 
  'name3': [3498]
}
```

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
dict = {}
for i in range(len(list1)): 
    for j in range(len(list1)): 
        if i == j: 
            dict.update({list1[i]:list2[i]})
```

dict: `{'name1': 4390, 'name2': 3498, 'name3': 1200}` and it over rights all but last value.

I also tried creating the dictionary first also

```
diff = np.unique(list1)
for i in diff: 
    dict.update({i:''})
```

but that results in
`{'name1': '', 'name2': '', 'name3': ''}` which doesn't work because of the empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name2', 'name1', 'name1']
list2 = [1424, 5243, 1200, 3498, 9087, 4390]

from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(list)
for name, value in zip(list1, list2):
    D[name].append(value)

print(D)
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'name1': [1424, 9087, 4390], 'name2': [5243, 3498], 'name3': [1200]})
```